# How to make a FitNesse test require explicit running

Tags: fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

Is there a way to mark a fitnesse test such that it will not be run as part of a suite, but it can still be run manually?

We have our FitNesse tests running as part of our continuous integration, so new tests that are not yet implemented cause the build to fail. We'd like a way to allow our testers and BAs to be able to add new tests that will fail while still continuing to validate the existing tests as part of continuous integration.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is with suite tags. You can mark tests with a tag from the properties page and then you can filter for the or filter to exclude them.

In this case I would exclude with "NotOnCI" tag.  Then add the following argument to the URL:

```
ExcludeSuiteFilter=NotOnCI
```

This might look like this then as the full URL:

```
Http://localhost:8080/FrontPage?test&ExcludeSuiteFilter=NotOnCI
```

You can select multiple tags by splitting with commas, but they act as "or",Not "and".

Check the FitNesse user guide for more details.  http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.TestSuites.TagsAndFilters

Answer (score 1):

Would it make sense to have multiple Suites, one for regression tests that should always pass, and another one for the tests that are not yet implemented?
Testers and BAs can add tests/suites to the latter suite and the CI server only runs tests in the former suite.
Once a developer believes he has implemented the behavior they can move the test/suite relating to that functionality to the 'regression' suite so that it will be checked in continuous integration.

This might make the status of a test/suite a bit more explicit/obvious than just having a tag. It would also provide a clear handover from development to test/BA to indicate the implementation is finished.

If you just want to have a test/suite not run during an overall run of a suite that contains the particular test/suite you could also just tick 'Skip (Recursive)' in the properties page of that test/suite (below 'Page Type').